# How to unit test an IntervalObservable

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, rxjs, karma-jasmine

In my Angular app, I make use of an [IntervalObservable](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/observable/IntervalObservable.js~IntervalObservable.html) in order to periodically perform some actions (in my case every 
5 minutes):

```
IntervalObservable.create(300000) // 5 minutes
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.someMethodReturningObs().subscribe((data) => {
      this.myData = data;
    });
  });
```

how I can unit test it?

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

To verify `this.myData` for every 5 mins.

```
it("should test data for 5min interval", fakeAsync(() => { 
tick(300000);
expect(myData).toBe(testValue);
}))
```

**Old Answer**

`Jasmine.clock` can be used for your puposes. 
Check the below example from [doc](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Mocking_the_JavaScript_Timeout_Functions)

```
beforeEach(function() {
    timerCallback = jasmine.createSpy("timerCallback");
    jasmine.clock().install();
  });
```

> Be sure to uninstall the clock after you are done to restore the
>   original timer functions.

```
afterEach(function() {
    jasmine.clock().uninstall();
  });
```

> Calls to any registered callback are triggered when the clock is
>   ticked forward via the jasmine.clock().tick function, which takes a
>   number of milliseconds.

```
it("causes a timeout to be called synchronously", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      timerCallback();
    }, 100);

    expect(timerCallback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

    jasmine.clock().tick(300000);

    expect(timerCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: in my case do I only need to use `jasmine.clock().tick(300000);` ? or should I set a `timerCallback` as well ? it is not very clear to me how this example relates to my case

Comment: Could you add more code details like what needs to be tested for every 5 mins?